# Swift 3 XML Parse Delegates not Called after data sent from Watch to Phone

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, watchkit

I'm trying to understand how delegates work for a project. The idea is to pick a section from a table view on the watch app and it parse the xml on the Phone. But when I click a section to start the Parser nothing happens.

So when the phone loads up I do the following.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    parser.delegate = self

    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        print("Phone Connected")
        session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}
```

When I click on a section to send the message to the phone from the watch I make try to begin parsing the data for the url.

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
    parseSection(s: message["section"]! as! String)
}

func parseSection(s: String){
    let link = "http://www.espn.com/espn/rss/" + s 
    let url : URL = URL(string: link)!
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
    parser.parse()
}
```

But the following delegates do nothing.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    print("Parser Begins")
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    print("Characters Found")
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    print("Parser Ends")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to implement the `XMLParserDelegate` protocol in order to get the parsing functions called. You already did that but you missed to set the delegate for the XMLParser:

```
func parseSection(s: String){
    let link = "http://www.espn.com/espn/rss/" + s 
    let url : URL = URL(string: link)!
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)!
    parser.delegate = self  // <-- set the delegate
    parser.parse()
}
```